# How do I calculate exponent (x^n) of a certain number (x) without self multiplication and without computers? Any efficient methods?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have a number 'x' raised to 'n', and I want to calculate the x^n without x.x.x.x....(n times). How do I do that? Is it possible to do it without the tedious self-multiplication?

(I mean to do it without computers)

I've been suggested using logarithms, but how efficient are they and do they have a limit?

Thanks

Comment: You have to calculate $100^{100}$ So let $100^{100} = x$ Raising log both sides $ 100log 100=log x $ so $x$ will be antilog$200$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It seems as if the question you linked is different to this one. Maybe you're supposed to send a related one?

Comment: Do you need an exact answer (assuming $x$ is an integer and $n$ is a nonnegative integer)? Either way, is $n$ a nonnegative integer?

Comment: If it's the number of multiplications that bothers you, you could reduce it by making intermediate results, for instance $3^{16}$ is $81^4$